# Algorithm for drawing box plot for given data

Tags: statistics, drawing, plot, boxplot

I have sorted array of real values, say `X`, drawn from some unknown distribution. I would like draw a box plot for this data.

In the simplest case, I need to know five values: `min`, `Q1`, `median`, `Q3`, and `max`.

Trivially, `min = X[0]`, `max = X[length(X)-1]`, and possibly `median = X[ceil(length(X)/2)]`. But I'm wondering how to determine the lower quartile `Q1` and `Q3`.

When I plot `X = [1,2,4]` using MATLAB, I obtain following result:

[image]

It seems to me like there is some magic how to obtain the values `Q1 = 1.25` and `Q3 = 3.5`, but I don't know what the magic is. Does anybody have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the original definition of box plots (look up John Tukey), you use the median for the midpoint (i.e., 2 in your data set of 1, 2, 4). The endpoints are the min and max.

The top and bottom of the box are not exactly defined by quartiles, instead they are called "hinges". Hinges are the medians of the top and bottom halves of the data. If there is an odd number of observations, the median of the entire set is used in determining both hinges. The lower hinge is the median of (1,2), or 1.5. The top hinge is the median of (2,4), or 3.

There are actually dozens of definitions of a box plot's quartiles (Wikipedia: "There is no universal agreement on choosing the quartile values"). If you want to rationalize MatLab's box plot, you'll have to check its documentation. Otherwise, you could Google your brains out to try to find a method that matches the results.

Minitab gives 1 and 4 for the hinges in your data set. Excel's PERCENTILE function gives 1.5 and 3, which incidentally matches Tukey's algorithm at least in this case.

Comment: Thanks @JonPeltier for your profound answer! I see that MATLAB has its specific solution for determining lower and upper hinge. I will try to mimic MATLAB's solution, because it looks nice for small amounts of data, but I understand that it is not the only possible solution. Anyway, you helped me a lot to understand how the algorithm should work in general -- thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The median devides the data into two halves. The median of the first half = Q1, and the median of the second half = Q3.

More info: http://www.purplemath.com/modules/boxwhisk.htm

---

Note on the MatLab boxplot: The Q1 and Q3 are maybe calculated in a different way in MatLab, I'd try with a larger amount of testing data. With my method, Q1 should be 1 and Q3 should be 4.

---

EDIT:

The possible calculation that MatLab does, is the difference between the median and the first number of the first half, and take a quarter of that. Add that to the first number to get Q1.
The same (roughly) applies to Q3: Take the difference between the median and the highest number, and subtract a quarter of that from the highest number. That is Q3.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I would expect (I do have some basic background in statistics). But in my application, I need the box plots to behave reasonably with this small amounts of data. There will be dynamic updates of the plot as new results will be continuously coming. Hence I need the plot to "look nice" in early stages. That is why I'd like to imitate box plots from MATLAB.

Comment: Read my edit. Not based on any proof, but a possible explanation on the numbers you get. I'd suggest trying with more triples of numbers, to see what MatLab produces for you.

Comment: I made some more experiments and the MATLAB algorithm really seems magic. For X=[1,3,4,5], it displays Q1=2, median=3.5, Q2=4.5. I don't get it. It seems like it uses fitting the data by some predefined distribution or something like that. Perhaps I'm sentenced to implement it in simple yet working way as you suggested earlier...

Comment: On your example [1, 3, 4, 5] the MatLab solution is really simple. The median is the average of the two middle numbers, 3+4/2 = 3.5, and we end up with two parts. [1, 3] and [4, 5]. The averages of those numbers in the sets are 2 and 3.5. I would try with some sets like [1, 2, 7], and see where you end up.

Comment: Thanks @Hidde, it seems that for length(X)=3, MATLAB takes X[1] as median, `0.75*X[0]+0.25*X[1]` as Q1 and `0.25*X[1]+0.75*X[2]`. For length(X)=4, `median=X[1]+X[2]`, `Q1=X[0]+X[1]` and `Q2=X[2]+X[3]`. Unfortunately, for length(X)=5, the situation gets complicated again. X=[1,2,3,4,7] gives `median=3`, Q1=1.75 and Q2=4.75. But, according to note made by @JonPeltier, there are multiple possible solutions for determining Q1 and Q3. Perhaps for length(X)>=5, I will use some simple method such as median of lower hinge to be Q1 and median of upper hinge to be Q3, as explained @JonPeltier.

Comment: Quite interesting actually, huge +1 for you! Good luck!